# Filter points between polygons

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, filtering

I have polygon like this:

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((3.6531688909 22.2345676543....)))
MULTIPOLYGON(((3.7531688909 22.6543234523....)))
…
```

[image]

And I have data like this (small part):

```
df = 

id_easy    latitude longitude
e705ac2     22.0171    3.6687
e705ac2     22.0238    3.6709
e705ac2     22.0299    3.6733
e705ac2     22.0319    3.6725
7eb84c8     22.0567    3.6821
3264cc7     22.0754    3.7277
3264cc7     22.0766    3.7208
3264cc7     22.0754    3.7163
3264cc7     22.0753    3.7102
```

Is it possible to check points started in one blue zone and ended in other blue zone?

For example, I need to check:  if locations of value `e705ac2` starting in left zone and ending in right zone

Answer (score 1):

What does your polygon data look like? Do you have geometry fields? If so, you could use [geopandas `contains`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.contains) to check if your blue polygons contain your points.

Comment: I edited the question, so you can see sample of polygon data

Comment: Cool. So looking at the data you posted, it looks like it would work fine with geopandas.